# Class works in Admin, not found on Front End

Tags: include

I'm using the SendGrid PHP library to send transactional emails on submission of new posts by the user, a simple submission received.

In the admin, it works perfectly. On the front end I get a class not found error.

As a test I threw this into functions.php

```
require( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/includes/vendor/sendgrid/sendgrid-php.php' );

if ( ! class_exists( 'SendGrid' ) ) {
   echo "Class Does Not Exist";
}
```

In the admin, it doesn't echo the string. But on the front end, it does.
Is there something that could be blocking the class being initiated on the front end that isn't present in the admin side?

Comment: Have you included the composer autoloader? I see a vendor folder there which suggests you pulled the library in via composer

Comment: I'm not using the composer version, instead loading it in the first line of the code above as documented in the library.

Comment: Then where did the vendor folder come from? You must have a composer autoloader that's only being loaded on the admin side and not the frontend

Comment: I named the containing folder vendor. It's not from composer.

Comment: Ah, that's confusing. Are you filtering on any URLs? Can you confirm the file being included is the same on both back and front end?